# Class with no name

Tags: c++, class, grammar, identifier

I read this about class in the C++ standard document:

> A class is a type. Its name becomes a class-name (9.1) within its
>   scope.
>
> ```
> class-name: identifier template-id
> ```

I found this grammar for an identifier in the C++ Standard:

```
 2.10 Identifiers
 identifier: nondigit
 identifier nondigit
 identifier digit

 nondigit: one of universal-character-name 
 _ a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u  v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 
 digit: one of 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Now I tried doing this:

```
class
{
public:
  int i;
};
```

and it compiles fine without any name.

Can anyone give me an explanation regarding this? Isn't it a violation of the grammar specified for an identifier?

---

Nawaz had asked a follow up question regarding the standard compliance of the code I had given. Those interested can check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138605/why-class-int-i-is-not-fully-standard-conformant).

Comment: I'd like to know what's the compiler you used: I'm not able to compile this code on GCC.

Comment: @AlbertoMoriconi I was using QtCreator(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator) for the same, so I guess that should be using GCC as well. Can you post the error you got ?

Comment: I get `error: abstract declarator ‘<anonymous class>’ used as declaration`

Comment: @AlbertoMoriconi Please go through the edit, I have added a link about a follow up question. Your doubt is also discussed there in one of the answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The grammar goes

```
class-specifier:
    class-head { member-specification_opt }

class-head:
    class-key attribute-specifier-seq_opt class-head-name class-virt-specifier-seq_opt base-clause_opt
    class-key attribute-specifier-seq_opt base-clause_opt

class-key:
    class
    struct
    union
```

In your case, the second production of `class-head` is used -- no `class-name` is involved.

Answer (score 0):

The identifier is omitted entirely, so the question of correct grammar for the identifier is moot. Nothing in the description says the identifier must be present. Anonymous classes are probably allowed for consistency with C struct rules, which allows constructs such as:

```
typedef struct { int i; } Foo;

struct { int x, y; } points[] = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };
```

I don't think I've ever seen this done for a class.

Comment: -1, the description he quotes says that an identifier must be present.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: that quote is irrelevant as far as the posted code is concerned.

Comment: you are saying "the description". i must be assuming you refer to the question.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Yes, I was referring to the quotations in the question. I can find nothing (quoted or otherwise) in any version of the question that says anything resembling "a class must have a name". What am I missing? I suppose I'll slap my forehead when you point it out, but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class {public: int i;}
```

is quite useless, but you can specyfy a class without a name and then create instances of this class. Knowing that you  can use the following:

```
class {public: int i;} a,b,c;
a.i = 5;
b.i = 4;
c.i = 3;
cout<<a.i<<" "<<b.i<<" "<<c.i;
```

You can use this inside a function too (as an anonimous class), so knowing that you can use something like this:

```
void x()
{
    class {public: int i;} a,b,c;
    a.i = 5;
    b.i = 4;
    c.i = 3;
    cout<<a.i<<" "<<b.i<<" "<<c.i;
}

int main() {
    x();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The code `class { int i; };` is fully-standard conformant.You've quoted the irrelevant reference from the Standard which has nothing to do with anonymous class.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb : `class { public: int i; };` is not fully standard conformant? why?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Could you please tell me what is wrong with `class { public: int i; };`? Why is not Standard conformant? (I'm waiting for your answer, so I may know it myself).

Comment: while it is grammatically valid, it breaks the rule that such a class must declare at least one name into its enclosing scope.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I didn't get it. What name are you talking about? Could you elaborate on it?

Comment: you may want to ask a Stackoverflow question if you are interested in elaborated explanations. These comment boxes are too small for that.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138605/why-class-int-i-is-not-fully-standard-conformant