# Why class { int i; }; is not fully standard-conformant?

Tags: c++, class, definition, identifier, standards-compliance

This is a follow-up question.

In the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134845/class-with-no-name/13134925#comment17869000_13134925), @JohannesSchaub-litb said that the following code is **not** fully standard-conformant:

```
class { int i; };  //unnamed-class definition. § 9/1 allows this!
```

and then he added,

> while it is grammatically valid, it breaks the rule that such a class must declare at least one name into its enclosing scope.

I couldn't really understand this. What name is he talking about?

Could anyone elaborate on this further (preferably quoting the Standard)?

Comment: What name is he talking about? The one that _is not there_. The declaration does not declare a class name, nor does it declare a typedef name or a variable/function -- nothing is added to the scope the declaration appears in as a result of the declaration.

Comment: It's the equivilent of writing : "int;" as a line of code. It names a type but doesn't give it a name.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Clause 9 of the standard allows `class {public: int i;}` (note the lack of a final semicolon) because this *decl-specifier-seq* for an unnamed class might be used in some other construct such as a typedef or a variable declaration. The problem with `class {public: int i;};` (note that the final semicolon is now present) is that this class specification now becomes a declaration. This is an illegal declaration per clause 7, paragraph 3 of the standard:

> In such cases, and except for the declaration of an unnamed bit-field (9.6), the *decl-specifier-seq* shall introduce one or more names into the program, or shall redeclare a name introduced by a previous declaration.

Comment: +1 for clarifying between *decl-specifier-seq* and a *declaration*.

Answer (score 26):

The point is that by declaring `class{ int i; };` you are assembling a bunch of symbol (`int i`, in this case) you will not be able to use anywhere else in whatever code.

For this code to make sense you should at least do one of the following:

```
class Myclass { int i; }; //I can furthermore instantiate variables of Myclass
class { int i; } myvar; //This in fact creates a myvar object
typedef class { int i; } MyType; //I can funthermore instantiate variables of MyType
```

By saying just `class{ int i; };` you are saying to the compiler:

- keep an `int` and name it `i`,
- wrap it into a `class` I'll never call and...
- forget it! (`};`)

If you remove that declaration from your program, nothing will change.

Comment: This is all good, but IMHO it needs to either agree or disagree with "this code is not standard-conformant" explicitly.

Comment: Obviously the class declaration is useless, but this does not answer the question of whether it is allowed. There are many useless constructs which are allowed by the standard. Why is it getting so many upvotes?

Comment: The OP asked for an explanation, not an agreement (he said "possibly" ...) As per the standard, every declaration must declare something. The proposed one declares nothing. I can understand that "nothing" can be seen as a particular "something", but is a sophism not permitted (the compiler assumes that "there must be something that as been forgotten", and this may be dangerous)

Comment: @Griwes: Maybe you should vote based on whether this answered the question instead.

Comment: @interjay, I voted for that. And wrote "+1", as in "good one", not "I'm upvoting you". I do differentiate "+1" and "Upvote".

Answer (score 11):

`class { int i; };` is not a valid declaration because it is a *simple-declaration* without an *init-declarator-list* but it doesn't introduce (or re-declare) a class name.

ISO/IEC 14882:2011 7 [dcl.dcl] / 3:

> In a *simple-declaration*, the optional *init-declarator-list* can be omitted only when declaring a class (Clause 9) or enumeration (7.2), that is, when the *decl-specifier-seq* contains either a *class-specifier*, an *elaboratedtype-specifier* with a *class-key* (9.1), or an *enum-specifier*. In these cases and whenever a *class-specifier* or *enum-specifier* is present in the *decl-specifier-seq*, the identifiers in these specifiers are among the names being declared by the declaration (as *class-names*, *enum-names*, or *enumerators*, depending on the syntax). **In such cases, and except for the declaration of an unnamed bit-field (9.6), the *decl-specifier-seq* shall introduce one or more names into the program, or shall redeclare a name introduced by a previous declaration.**

Answer (score 10):

The error message from GCC explains it quite succinctly:

```
$ cat > a.cc
class { int i; };
$ g++ -Wall -std=c++98 a.cc
a.cc:1: error: abstract declarator ‘<anonymous class>’ used as declaration
```

`class { int i; }` is an *abstract-declarator* (Standard, §8) but not a valid *declaration* (§7). That's the rule that @JohannesSchaub-litb referenced: for a valid declaration, you need something to be declared, e.g. a class name or variable name.

Answer (score 3):

You are breaking the the `[basic.scope.pdecl]/6`, which says :

> The point of declaration of a class first declared in an elaborated-type-specifier is as follows:
>   — for a declaration of the form
>       `class-key attribute-specifier-seqopt identifier ;`
>
> the identifier is declared to be a class-name in the scope that contains the declaration, otherwise
>   — for an elaborated-type-specifier of the form
>      `class-key identifier`
>
> if the elaborated-type-specifier is used in the decl-specifier-seq or parameter-declaration-clause of a
>   function defined in namespace scope, the identifier is declared as a class-name in the namespace that
>   contains the declaration; otherwise, except as a friend declaration, the identifier is declared in the
>   smallest namespace or block scope that contains the declaration. [ Note: These rules also apply within
>   templates. — end note ] [ Note: Other forms of elaborated-type-specifier do not declare a new name,
>   and therefore must refer to an existing type-name. See 3.4.4 and 7.1.6.3. — end note ]

1. you are not creating a variable of an anonymous type
2. you are not create a type

There is another example (in `[basic.def]/2`) from the standard that proves your example is not standard compliant :

```
struct S { int a; int b; };       // defines S, S::a, and S::b
struct X {                        // defines X
  int x;                          // defines non-static data member x
  static int y;                   // declares static data member y
  X(): x(0) { }                   // defines a constructor of X
};
int X::y = 1;                     // defines X::y
enum { up, down };                // defines up and down
namespace N { int d; }            // defines N and N::d
namespace N1 = N;                 // defines N1
X anX;                            // defines anX
```

Your example doesn't define anything (except an anonymous struct, who's fields can not be accessed).

Note an exception about the enum, because this case introduces two values to use.